# Transform an expression to remove the singularity

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I have the expression `Sin[c x]/c`. Clearly it is undefined at $c=0$, but that is merely a removable singularity, since
$$\frac{\sin(cx)}c=x\frac{\sin(cx)}{cx}= x\operatorname{sinc}(cx),$$
which is continuous everywhere. Is it possible to get this sort of transformation automatically in Mathematica using the built-in formula manipulation tools? I tried a few things like `FullSimplify`, `TrigReduce`, etc. but nothing helped.

I'd like to be able to do this for `(1 - Cos[c x])/c`, too; that is, automatically transform it into a form that has no singularity at $c=0$.

Comment: You can go backwards: `FunctionExpand[x Sinc[c x]]`

Comment: @bill: I suppose what I need is a `FunctionReduce` along the lines of `TrigExpand`/`TrigReduce`. :)

Comment: I can't even find a way to go back from `Sin[c x]/(c x)` to `Sinc[c x]`. One would think there should be some kind of `ComplexityFunction` that could be used with `FullSimplify` to achieve this.

Comment: Is `Sin[x_] :> x Sinc[x_]` what you're looking for in the first case?  Coincidentally, it's what I've been using this afternoon. :)

Comment: Ditto for `Cos[z_] :> 1 - (z Sinc[z])^2/(1 + Cos[z])` for the second case?

Comment: @Michael, or `Cos[z_] :> 1 - (z Sinc[z/2])^2/2`…

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, if I do a bunch of trigonometry to derive the appropriate substitution I can then plug it into Mathematica, but it would be nice to have a more automatic solution.

Comment: What we really need is a big big table of rules for `FunctionExpand` so we can do reverse lookups.

Answer (score 10):

One idea is to extend the domain with a piecewise function by taking limits at singularities.

```
ExtendFunctionDomain[expr_, vars_] := Module[{domain, antidomain, locassums, lims},
  domain = FunctionDomain[expr, vars, Reals] /. {
    NotElement[f_, S_] :> Not[f == C[1] && Element[C[1], S]]
  };
  antidomain = Reduce`ToDNF[Reduce[!domain, vars, Reals]];

  locassums = ExtractRootsAndAssumptions[antidomain];
  If[!MatchQ[locassums, {{{_Rule}, _}..}],
    Return[expr]
  ];

  lims = ExtendedLimit[expr, ##]& @@@ locassums;
  If[!FreeQ[lims, $Failed],
    Return[expr]
  ];

  Piecewise[MapThread[{#1, (And @@ Equal @@@ #2[[1]]) && #2[[2]]}&, {lims, locassums}], expr]
]

ExtractRootsAndAssumptions[HoldPattern[Or][args__]] := 
  iExtractRootsAndAssumptions /@ {args}

ExtractRootsAndAssumptions[expr_] := {iExtractRootsAndAssumptions[expr]}

iExtractRootsAndAssumptions[expr_] := With[{r = Reduce`ReduceToRules[expr]},
  (
    {First[r], expr /. First[r]}
  ) /; MatchQ[r, {{__Rule}}]
];
iExtractRootsAndAssumptions[_] = $Failed;

ExtendedLimit[expr_, {x_ -> a_}, assum_] := Module[{llim, rlim},
  llim = Limit[expr, x -> a, Assumptions -> assum, Direction -> 1];
  rlim = Limit[expr, x -> a, Assumptions -> assum, Direction -> -1];

  badTerms = ComplexInfinity|Indeterminate|Undefined|DirectedInfinity|Interval;

  (
    Switch[FreeQ[#, badTerms]& /@ {llim, rlim},
      {True, True}, (llim + rlim)/2,
      {True, False}, llim,
      {False, True}, rlim,
      _, Undefined
    ]
  ) /; FreeQ[{llim, rlim}, Limit]
];
ExtendedLimit[___] = $Failed;
```

I haven't tested this code on many examples, but here are some.

```
ExtendFunctionDomain[Sin[x c]/c, {x, c}]
```

[image]

```
ExtendFunctionDomain[(1 - Cos[c x])/c, {x, c}]
```

[image]

```
ExtendFunctionDomain[2 Cos[x] Sin[x] Csc[2 x], x]
```

[image]

Comment: What's this `Reduce\`ToDNF`? Could it be replaced with properly documented `BooleanConvert`?

Comment: A typo in `Switch[FreeQ[#, badTemrs]& /@ {llim, rlim}` should be `badTerms`? @Greg Hurst

Comment: Fixed, thanks! $ $

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is only for $\frac{1-cos[c x]}{c}$, I tried the following which works perfectly (even without assumptions):

```
FullSimplify[((1 - Cos[c x])/(c x))/ Sinc[c x]] Sinc[c x]
```

which in turn yields:

```
Sinc[c x] Tan[(c x)/2]
```

I am not sure about the bigger context where you want to use that, expanding this technique depends on what you want to do exactly.